# Is there a cross-platform way to create a struct or a list of .mat file names on MATLAB

Tags: windows, matlab, unix

Trying to load a bunch of .mat files in MATLAB. I am using *list* function (`ls`) to create an array of chars and taking each line into `load` function to load into my program. However, because `ls` performs differently on different platforms, when I took my code (coded on Windows) and took it to another computer (UNIX), obviously there was an error. Is there a way to create a struct or a list of .mat file names that works on both UNIX and Windows?

EDIT: example code (runs in Windows)

```
files = ls('*.mat'); % list of all .mat file 
for i=1:1:length(files) 
    data = function(files(i,:));
end
```

Comment: Can you show some code to demonstrate what you presently have?

Comment: files = ls('*.mat'); % list of all .mat file
    
    for i=1:1:length(files)
    
       data = function(files(i,:));
    
    end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `dir` command should be consistent.  It generates a `struct` with the `name` field containing the name of the file.

```
files = dir('*.mat');
for i=1:1:length(files) 
    data = function(files(i).name);
end
```

Comment: Glad it helped!  Welcome to SO.